# How to show a django-tables2 Table in a form while keeping its sort working?

Tags: django, django-tables2

I have a simple `forms.Form` with `forms.ChoiceField` in it. Below on the same page is a django-tables2 `Table`. The `ChoiceField` drives selection criteria for a query that feeds the table. Simple. The `ChoiceField` sits inside a form:

```
<body>
<form action="/e/n/" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ choiceFieldForm }}
  <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>

{% render_table table %}

</body>
```

In my `urls.py` I have:

```
urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^$', views.start, name='start'),
  url(r'^n/$', views.n, name='n'),
]
```

And in my `views.py` I have:

```
def n(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    # handle "submit" button click
  else:
    # !!! table sort sends GET here
```

The problem is when I click on a table column to sort data, it sends GET on the same URL with the form: `/e/n/`. In order to return rendered template, I need to assemble the `context` with all the fields on the page, including the table itself. Now as I mentioned earlier, to pull table data I need to know the currently selected value of `ChoiceField`, which is *not* coming with this GET request.

What am I missing?

A am thinking, either have the table send GET on a different URL, so that its column sorting does not interfere with the data on the page. Or figure out how to send necessary data with the GET, so it can be used to re-create output.

Comment: I have several views with a similar structure that work fine. However, I use `get` as form method. Sorting the table then doesn't change the current table queryset. (The querystring of the form get params remains)

Comment: @schwobaseggl: so you are saying, you table's `GET` is not getting routed to the same url handler? If that is the case, then I am clearly missing something. Let me try to experiment with changing my form's `POST` to `GET` in the meantime...

Comment: Yes, they are, but the sorting get params of the table just merrily mix with the form get params.

Comment: In that case, let me look closely at what's in that `GET`.

Comment: If you inspect the `href` attr of the links in the table header in the html, you will see that the initial get-querystring (from the form) is rendered into them.

Comment: @schwobaseggl: I think we have it solved, sort-of. First, thank you very much for guiding me. I spent many hours trying before resorting to post here. Now here's what I observe: when I change `method="get"`, everything works (requests from the form and from table sort both send `GET` and the params are all there). If I change it to `method="post"`, then `GET` requests from table column sort come without any form related params at all.

Comment: technically you are breaking convention by using GET for posting data to the server from the forms... it also sounds much more complex than needed. have you considered using javascript (jQuery and DataTables.net script are great tools for something like this!).

Comment: @warath-coder Not really. It seems, the form data is merely used for filtering the data thats being displayed in the table. Thus, you are not changing any data. This kind of sorting and filtering parameters are canonical for `GET`